# jQuery, delay button reset - twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, button, twitter-bootstrap, delay, reset

Is there a way to delay the button reset on jQuery?

I tried this one:

```js
$('.deposit-cur-btn').delay(3000).button('reset');
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Try .button('reset').delay(3000);

Comment: I've never had `delay` do anything for me. I've always had to use setTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what .button('reset') does, but you can try something like this

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('.deposit-cur-btn').button('reset'); }, 3000);
```

Comment: sorry, its not jquery its bootstrap -> http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons